# How do you use Spanned Strings from a hashmap to populate a SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a Hashmap defined by `ArrayList<HashMap<Spanned, String>>();`

As you can see I have a Spanned String and a normal string that I want put into a listview in two columns as the following code should do. But my problem is that the adapter throws an error saying that the constructor is undefined. If anyone could help me out with what I have done wrong, I would appreciate it, thanks!

```
mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<Spanned, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
            map2 = new HashMap<Spanned, String>();

            map2.put(Html.fromHtml("slno"), String.valueOf(i + 1));
            map2.put(Html.fromHtml("one"), move[i]);
            map2.put(Html.fromHtml("two"), comb[i]);
            mylist.add(map2);
        }
        try {
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.two_row,
                    new String[] {"one","two"}, new int[] {R.id.one, R.id.two});
            listn.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listn);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: is this code written inside Fragment or activity?

Comment: Can you post the function in which this code is written? I suspect, problem maybe with "this" in first argument. Which might be referring to a local class object.

Comment: "this" refers to the context of the class.